# Can I use AEM as OAuth 2.0 client?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, aem, aem-6

Does Adobe Experience Manager support OAuth 2.0 as a client? I mean AEM connecting with an external application which plays a role of authorization server and resource provider.

I could not find any examples of such usage - AEM is usually presented as an authorization server and resource provider for other client applications.

Comment: I have found a working example with a detailed doc:
https://github.com/thegreyteacher/aem-social-login

Answer (score 4):

AEM provides an number of authorization integrations. Maybe you can switch to SAML, which works pretty good out-of-the-box. I once integrated AEM with Keycloak with good results (but using SAML).

Regarding OAuth most documentation is dominated by AEM as an OAuth provider. They integrated Apache Oltu (which is end-of-life anyway).

But AEM provides an OAuth client as well. But it needs a custom extension for each provider. Out-of-the-box are only implementations for [Twitter and Facebook](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/communities/administer/social-login.html) available. But there seems also Github and IMS (Identity Management from Adobe Managed Services) to be available.

Please check also Package Share. But I don't know what is available there. And you probably need support from Adobe, to judge the quality and usefulness of such packages.

If you have to implement your own Provider-Extension, the best starting point I found was here:

https://aemcorner.com/adobe-granite-oauth-authentication-handler/

Answer (score 0):

You are basically free to build whatever you want, as AEM is basically nothing else but a Java application. But you might want to keep in mind, that the standard applications of AEM are delivering rendered HTML from the dispatcher in the end. You want to have as little load on the publishers as possible.

So, when authorisation of resources is a technical- or business concern, you might need to dive deeper into SPAs or at least async loading of resources as JSON.